# crystal report Text object overlap

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, overlap

i am creating crystal report for win-forms. I have crystal report shown in image.The top text object overlapping the other text object.I have set both text object property of can grow to zero.i have tried keep together option but not working.What could be done here?I want to set space between these two objects.Any one have solution for this?

here is the screenshot of report:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put each object into its own section in the same area (depending on what version of Crystal you're using, this would be done in the equivalent of the 'section expert').  This way, each section will size appropriately for the content (you can turn on can grow property if you want) and not overlap with objects in the section below.

[Here's an article](http://arsalantamiz.blogspot.ca/2008/09/how-to-handle-overlapping-of-large-text.html) that describes doing exactly this (the article demos doing this on the report footer, but the process is the same for any area).